# Final de vida de una pregunta en meta

Tags: discusión

Si bien en Meta el sentido de votar se sobreentiende que es para apoyar o no una propuesta, ¿tiene algún sentido votar para "cerrar" la pregunta, más cuando las razones habituales no parecen las adecuadas para preguntas en meta? En relación con elegir una respuesta, ¿quién debería dar por respondida la pregunta, el usuario o un moderador?

Hace varias semanas hice una pregunta en meta y no parece que haya tenido suficientes apoyos. No tengo claro si ahora debo hacer algo para cerrarla o, si bien, debo dejarla olvidada hasta que algún moderador más adelante decida hacer algo con ella.

Comment: Hola @ChemaCortes. ¿A qué te refieres con "cerrar" la pregunta? Este sitio no es como los otros foros de internet donde el concepto de "cerrado" es que el hilo ya no acepta más publicaciones porque se encontró una respuesta, sino que se cierra una pregunta porque no es válida o aceptable. ¿Podrías aclarar un poco tu inquietud?

Comment: No me hagas mucho caso, pero cuando en meta es aceptable opinar, no veo un motivo para cerrar una pregunta que tenga algo de sentido. En todo caso, se podrá votar a favor o en contra. Lo que realmente me inquieta es saber qué ocurre después. En el foro normal, el usuario elige la respuesta que considera correcta; pero en meta no parece lo adecuado. No se indica qué debe hacer el usuario, si dejar que algún moderador la tenga en cuenta según los votos, o si debería, por voluntad propia, cerrarla/borrarla por no tener suficientes apoyos. ...o quizás olvidarse de ella, que parece lo más habitual.

Comment: Sigo sin entender tu punto @ChemaCortes. Si tu duda es respecto a qué significa "cerrar" una pregunta, pues en todo stackexchange el significado de "cerrar" es "mala pregunta, no apoya a que el sitio crezca, no deberían publicarse preguntas similares, por favor no responder". Si te refieres a qué sucede cuando se acepta una respuesta, significa "el usuario considera esta respuesta como la mejor para su pregunta" pero no significa que la comunidad apoye a esa respuesta totalmente, para eso están los votos a favor y en contra.

Comment: Vale, intentaré ser mucho más claro. Esta pregunta ha sido una solemne tontería. ¿Qué hago ahora?¿Elijo algún motivo de cierre?¿Pido que se elimine? ¿Mejor lo dejo estar y que el tiempo se encargue de su destino?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres dar por  "concluido" un tema que has abierto en Meta, y no hay ninguna respuesta, publica una tu mismo y pasado el tiempo requerido acéptala.

En la respuesta puedes indicar las razones por las cuales das por concluído el tema.

Una alternativa es dejar la pregunta tal cual y dejar que los algoritmos de SO ES se hagan cargo de ella. Si mal no recuerdo, una pregunta que no ha recibido ninguna respuesta y ningún voto a favor se eliminará automáticamente después de un año.

Comment: Quizás era éso lo que buscaba. Tendría que haber hablado desde el principio de *"concluir"* en lugar de *"cerrar"* la pregunta. Gracias, @Rubén

Comment: Pues piénsalo y nos avisas :)