# ¿Por qué se cierran preguntas tan rápidamente sin preguntar primero?

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas, pregunta-específica

No estoy nada contento con la gente que hay en este foro y quiero borrar esta cuenta de forma inmediata.

Cerrando preguntas a diestro y siniestro sin preguntar primero creo que lo único que conseguís es que la gente deje de usar el foro.

Comment: Es una pena que quieras hacer eso .. No te lo tomes *tan a pecho*.. unos votan para cerrar pero si la pregunta es válida se reabrirá. Respecto a este sitio, no es un **foro**. Un saludo

Comment: Creo que la pregunta será reabierta. A algunos no les gusta que se compare esta comunidad con su homóloga en inglés pero en casos como estos es inevitable. Lo digo porque la misma pregunta existe y tiene buena acogida en inglés. Es un contrasentido además cerrar este tipo de preguntas cuando veo constantemente preguntas relanzadas por la comunidad que son mucho peores que esta. A mi me ocurrió algo parecido a ti al principio. La solución no es el divorcio, sino decir con franqueza lo que piensas y mejorar la pregunta si es posible, lo cual has hecho. De todo se aprende.

Comment: @Samsung Developer realmente la pregunta **¿Cómo puedo borrar mi cuenta?** es muy buena, me imagino que los -1, sera por lo que expones a continuacion, quizas alguno se sienta ofendido, pero sobre lo de abandonar el lugar usted es libre jaja, pero en este mundo ya se sabe que existe de todo yo lo unico que le puedo decir es que, **Sea usted el cambio que quiere ver** he intentar mejorar lo que no le gusta.Saludos

Comment: ¿El +1 en esta pregunta significa estar de acuerdo con que el OP cierre la cuenta o querer borrar su propia cuenta también?

Comment: Para cumplir la máxima una pregunta, una publicación, he editado la pregunta inicial para centrar el debate en el cabreo del usuario. Creo una pregunta aparte para la explicación de cómo borrar una cuenta: [¿Cómo puedo borrar mi cuenta? ¿Qué pasa con el contenido que he publicado?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2550/83)

Comment: @Shaz El +1 en esta y en todas las preguntas significa "Esta pregunta demuestra trabajo de investigación; es útil y clara". Yo voto +1 con frecuencia en preguntas en que estoy en desacuerdo sobre temas que creo son interesantes. Exponer en qué estás descontento es siempre uno de los primeros pasos para remediarlo, por eso es útil. Aunque algo de trabajo de investigación le ha faltado, si hubiese tenido paciencia habría visto su pregunta abierta, con votos en positivo y buenas respuestas.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos Los votos en meta son diferentes que en el SOes, la gente suele votar si está de acuerdo con lo que se plantea o no, es un voto subjetivo. Al menos yo siempre lo he entendido así y creo recordar que se trataba el tema en algún sitio pero no consigo encontrarlo

Comment: @blonfu Eso requiere de una citación.

Comment: Ahora mismo solo encuentro esta referencia al tema: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/541/final-de-vida-de-una-pregunta-en-meta dónde Chema dice:  _Si bien en Meta el sentido de votar se sobreentiende que es para apoyar o no una propuesta(...)_

Comment: @blonfu [voting in Meta is different](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187018/209901) por ejemplo.

Comment: @fedorqui Lo que leo en la respuesta de Shog9 a tu enlace es que "voting on meta isn't all that different". Y también explica que el mostrarse de acuerdo o en desacuerdo es para preguntas del tipo feature-request y similares. Que alguien quiera borrar su cuenta no es algo con lo que tengamos que mostrarnos en acuerdo o desacuerdo, eso es asunto suyo. Por eso en esta pregunta los votos tienen el significado habitual, otra vez citando a Shog9: "For most posts, votes reflect the perceived usefulness: well-written, well-reasoned, well-researched posts tend to get more attention and more upvotes"

Comment: Naturalmente eso significa que mi afirmación de que " El +1 en esta y en todas las preguntas significa[...]" era excesiva. Hay preguntas o respuestas en que tiene otro significado, estar en acuerdo o desacuerdo. Pero esta no es una de esas.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos quizá tengas razón, yo daba por supuesto que en meta era diferente. Si no hay nada en nuestro meta o las faq que trate el tema podríamos debatirlo en una nueva pregunta, al menos por saber que criterios usa la gente para votar en meta.

Comment: @Jose bien expuesto y analizado, tiene mucho sentido. No me detuve a mirar la respuesta de Shog9, busqué simplemente alguna pregunta de Meta SE donde se repitiera ese "mantra". Por cierto, a través de tu comentario luego llegué a nuestro propio FAQ: [¿Qué es "meta" y cómo funciona?](/help/whats-meta) que traduce esto que comentas de que en Meta el voto es diferente en preguntas etiquetadas como [meta-tag:característica-nueva]. Dicho lo cual, parece obvio que los votos en esta y tantas preguntas de Meta pueden significar mil cosas independientemente de cómo esté redactada.

Answer (score 8):

Entiendo que parte de tu descontento venga de lo comentado en tu reciente pregunta [Diferencias entre file_get_contents() y curl](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/81565/83), por lo que permite que comente el tema pues he estado involucrado.

He visto algunas preguntas tuyas como la que enlazo. En ellas planteas preguntas muy genéricas, útiles sin duda, pero que -para mí- no cumplen los requisitos para ser consideradas válidas en este sitio. A saber, planteas dudas como la diferencia entre `file_get_contents()` y `curl()` pero sin ofrecer ningún tipo de investigación al respecto. Te lo hice notar diciendo:

> ¿Qué has investigado? ¿Qué no has entendido al respecto? Es importante indicar esfuerzo, máxime cuando llevas tantas preguntas y tiempo en el sitio. ¡Debes ser un referente de cómo preguntar!

Contestaste diciendo que habías añadido tres enlaces (el comentario está borrado ahora), a lo que añadí:

> No creo que añadir tres enlaces aporte demasiado. La cosa es: ¿qué has probado? ¿qué te ha funcionado? ¿qué no? Si lo que pretendes es crear una pregunta canónica, puede serte útil leer [¿Es válido realizar preguntas sin mostrar esfuerzo si no es para poner una respuesta propia al mismo tiempo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2156/83). Resumiéndolo, si quieres crear contenido en base a preguntas genéricas, lo que la comunidad agradecería es que contestaras tú mismo. De lo contrario no queda clara la finalidad de la pregunta.

Comentaste tú después:

> ¿Como voy yo a contestar si no se la respuesta? Si pregunto será por algo, las preguntas estan claras. He probado las dos, me ha funcionado pero quiero saber que diferencias hay y cual es la mas apropiado para el uso que le voy a dar @fedorqui

Y yo finalmente dije:

> El primer enlace que muestras lo explica muy bien. ¿Qué no te quedó claro al respecto? Nótese que aquí se responde *ayudando* a comer, no dando de comer.

Hoy he visto que se cerró tu pregunta como *se basa en opiniones*. No comparto el motivo de cierre, creo que la pregunta cojeaba inicialmente y que tus ulteriores ediciones la mejoraron bastante como para que permanezca abierta.

Creo que en general estás aportando preguntas fantásticas a la comunidad ([la última que has formulado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/81584/83) por ejemplo) y te animo a reconsiderar tu decisión.

En otra pregunta te mencioné lo mismo y te animé a debatirlo en [¿Es válido realizar preguntas sin mostrar esfuerzo si no es para poner una respuesta propia al mismo tiempo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2156/83). ¡Hazlo! Estamos creando la comunidad e intentando definir la manera de colaborar positivamente. Si crees que este tipo de preguntas sí tiene cabida, razónalo y lo mismo conseguimos un punto intermedio que nos contente a todos. Mientras tanto, yo seguiré insistiendo en que o bien preguntes cosas mostrando investigación, o bien hagas preguntas más genéricas si a continuación vas a publicar una respuesta tú mismo.

---

Si igualmente consideras que debes eliminar tu cuenta, lee [¿Cómo borro mi cuenta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2550/83)

Comment: He visto **varias** preguntas _relanzadas por la Comunidad_ que son mucho más pobres que esta. Así que lo veo como un contrasentido que por un lado cerremos preguntas que podrían tener respuestas interesantes y relancemos algunas que son verdaderas _chapuzas_. Para ser sincero, creo que no pocos aprietan el botón _cerrar_ de forma poco consciente. Y creo también que algunos son _estrechos_ de visión, con todo respeto.

Comment: @A.Cedano te refieres a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/819182/1983854) como homóloga? Nótese que esa pregunta se publicó en 2009, cuando [so] recién empezaba y las reglas eran mucho más laxas. El tiempo hizo ver que valía la pena pedir esfuerzo e investigación por parte de quien pregunta, que es lo que finalmente incluyó Samsung Developer en la pregunta que estamos comentando. En cuanto a que ves constantemente preguntas relanzadas por la comunidad, no acabo de entender a qué te refieres (¿a [esto](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1650/83)? en tal caso son cosas distintas).

Comment: @A.Cedano en cuanto a _cerrar de forma poco consciente_ y _estrechos de visión_, creo que estás asumiendo un nivel superior de conocimiento que no resulta demasiado productivo para el debate. Estoy detallando razones y motivos, tanto genéricos como concretos. Te animo a proceder de la misma forma para contrastar las ideas y llegar a algún punto de encuentro.

Comment: @A.Cedano sobre lo de _He visto varias preguntas relanzadas por la Comunidad que son mucho más pobres que esta_, destaco lo que dice [¿Qué puede causar que una pregunta sea relanzada?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1651/83): _El usuario Comunidad relanzará preguntas que no tuvieron actividad durante 30 días, no puntuadas negativamente, y que tengan al menos una respuesta con un puntaje de 0 y ninguna con puntaje positivo_. Por tanto, evitarlo es tan fácil como votarlas negativamente si es pertinente. La moderación está en nuestras manos, eso no debemos olvidarlo nunca.

Comment: Lo que es válido y no lo es en este sitio ¿Está cerrado de alguna manera a estas alturas? ¿Sería posible votarlo entre todos los que conformamos esta comunidad? Porque lo que no tiene sentido es que unos se empeñen en hacer de esta comunidad la homologa de SO en español, y otros no quieran dejar de marcar diferencias con esta y tener que estar recordando constantemente que esto no es SO y que los objetivos son diferentes.

Comment: @Muriano muy buen punto. Según entiendo, esto siempre estará en evolución. Sin embargo, tenemos una gran herramienta llamada Meta donde debatirla e intentar llegar a consensos. Yo lo planteé en [¿Es válido realizar preguntas sin mostrar esfuerzo si no es para poner una respuesta propia al mismo tiempo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2156/83), ¿te apetece darle un vistazo y aportar tu punto de vista? Cuanto más gente opine más podremos pulir cómo actuar.

Comment: Gracias @fedorqui, también he intentado aportar mi granito a ese tema.