# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar mi usuario de solamente un sitio de Stack Exchange?

Tags: soporte, stackexchange, eliminación-de-usuarios

Tengo una duda relacionada a la pregunta [¿Cómo puedo borrar mi cuenta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2237/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-borrar-mi-cuenta/2239#2239)

Yo no quiero eliminar la cuenta en Stack Exchange, pero por ejemplo sí quisiera salir/eliminar mi usuario de un sitio de la red por ejemplo el de ubuntu.

Como se comenta en la pregunta que mencioné antes, si elimino mi cuenta, ¿se elimina mi cuenta general en Stack Exchange o qué pasa exactamente?

Comment: La verdad es que la información es confusa. En la referencia oficial [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7979/209901) mencionan que el proceso descrito en la otra pregunta aplica a la cuenta de un solo sitio. Sin embargo, si haces la prueba y vas al formulario de contacto para solicitarlo, en ningún momento se explicita esto. Pero sí, juraría que si lo pides solamente te borrará en una. Haz la prueba ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La eliminación de un perfil se realiza **para un solo sitio**.
Si quisieras eliminar tu perfil de toda la red, deberías realizar una solicitud por cada sitio en el que participes.

> Una vez que solicites una eliminación, el proceso es **irreversible**.
> Esta información se encuentra en la ayuda: [¿Cómo borro mi cuenta?](/help/deleting-account)

#### 1. Si votaste o publicaste 1 sola vez como máximo

Dentro de tu propio perfil, se encuentra la opción en "*Edición de perfil y configuración*":

[image: Opción para "eliminar perfil"]

#### 2. Usuarios que hayan votado o publicado en el sitio más de 1 vez

Deberías ir al [formulario de contacto](/contact) (en este enlace, o en el pie de cualquier página del sitio) y completarlo.

En el mismo, es necesario incluir el enlace a tu perfil. Notarás que ese enlace es al perfil de un solo sitio de la red. Ese es el perfil que se eliminará.

Si quisieras eliminar todos los perfiles de todos los sitios, deberías hacerlo de a uno (no ingreses tu perfil global en Stack Exchange, porque lo tomará como inválido).

Ten en cuenta que las eliminaciones pueden tardar algunos días, ya que en la mayoría de los casos son procesadas y revisadas por una persona.

[image: formulario de contacto]

El contenido que publicaste en el sitio es de tu autoría, pero fue licenciado a Stack Overflow, por lo tanto no podrás solicitar que sea eliminado junto a tu perfil.

Si quisieras anonimizar completamente tu nombre al ser eliminado, de todos los lugares donde aparece, deberías también modificar tu nombre de usuario. Debido a [una característica](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155901/304899), tu nombre podría seguir apareciendo en las publicaciones que votaste para cerrar, entre otros lugares.

---

<sup>* Adaptado de [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5999/304899)</sup>