# ¿Cómo borrar totalmente una cuenta, contenido incluido?

Tags: discusión

> NOTAS:
>
> - Mi pregunta **no** tiene respuesta en [¿Cómo funciona la eliminación de publicaciones? ¿Por qué podría eliminarse una
>     publicación y qué implica? ¿Cuál es el criterio para eliminar?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1033/29967) como indica la nota que considera la pregunta duplicada.
> - Las respuestas dadas, indicando que SO se hace propietario de nuestro contenido inducen a error, el punto 3 lo que dice es que **yo
>     doy a SO una licencia para usar mi contenido, no que lo hago
>     propietario del mismo**.
> - Quizá sea esta la respuesta que más sirva para aclarar la duda planteada en mi pregunta:
>     [Alternativas al borrado de contenido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2539/alternativas-al-borrado-de-contenido)

---

En esta pregunta se explicó el procedimiento para borrar una cuenta: [¿Cómo puedo borrar mi cuenta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2237/29967)

Pero en ella no se explica el procedimiento para borrar también el contenido: preguntas y respuestas al mismo tiempo.

¿Existe alguna manera de hacerlo, de forma que no tengas que subsistir cual fantasma en esta red?

Sirva esta pregunta también como despedida, por mi parte, de esta comunidad.

Gracias.

Comment: Si es duplicada.

Comment: Los usuarios superior a 10 mil puntos de reputación... Bueno, en fin, [lee el privilegio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

Comment: También puedes pedir que se disocie el contenido de tu cuenta. Sea como fuere, qué pena me dará si esto acaba pasando. Como indica gbianchi, tómatw un tiempo de descanso y vuelve. La comunidad es mejor con tus aportes.

Comment: Opinión personal: Al borrar tus contenidos no le ganas a la persona que te ofendió, mas bien afectas a las personas que deseabas ayudar.

Porque todo el material que ha servido para responder sus dudas, se perderá.

Por otro lado, Me parece que deberías quedarte porque tu contenido enriquece al sitio. 

Relajate, tomate un break y luego regresa, en cualquier lugar siempre habrá diferencias, no te dejes dominar y tomar acciones que luego te hagan arrepentir.

No seria justo que por pocas personas que te hallan ofendido, el sitio y las personas que desean aprender sean afectadas :)

Comment: Sería una pena verte irte del sitio. Creo que tus respuestas son muy constructivas y bien elaboradas. Te propongo que si has pasado por una mala etapa o has tenido ofensas personales, como he podido leer en algunos comentarios, te tomes un respiro. Siempre es bueno desconectar y ver las cosas con más calma. Y siempre hay gente que te irá a hacer daño pero no por ello debes de dejar de ayudar a las buenas personas. Si todos actuaran de esta manera, en el foro y en la vida en general, se extinguiría el universo.

Comment: sé que no me conoces, nunca hablé contigo ni nada, pero créeme que si te vas, sería una total desgracia, eres un usuario muy experimentado en el sitio, aportando maravillas de respuestas generalmente siempre, espero que reconsideres, y que, al menos, primero te des un respiro antes de tomar una decisión así.

Comment: Quizás te interese : [Alternativas al borrado de contenido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2539/alternativas-al-borrado-de-contenido)

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos gracias. Interesante respuesta que aclara muchas de mis dudas. Me parecía sorprendente que SO se apropiase de mi contenido y que luego tenga que citar a SO si quería usar _mi_ contenido posteriormente.

Comment: Mas allá de que nuestra visión del sitio evidentemente no coincide, es una pena si finalmente decides abandonar la comunidad ya que es indiscutible que tus aportaciones se echaran en falta y mucho. Creo que deberías pensarlo, en todas las redes sociales hay gente que se ampara en el anonimato para no respetar a los demás, pero hay que saber abstraerse y quedarse con la gente que si merece la pena (que aquí la hay y mucha). Si decides irte, te deseo suerte en tus proyectos. Un saludo.

Answer (score 3):

No, lo siento pero no puedes hacer desaparecer tu cuenta. todo lo que publicaste esta bajo licencia para su uso por SO.

Entonces podrias dar de baja la cuenta.. pero el acuerdo que firmaste al dar de alta la cuenta dice:

> 3. Subscriber Content
>
> You agree that all Subscriber Content that You contribute to the
>   Network is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange
>   under the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license. You grant
>   Stack Exchange the perpetual and irrevocable right and license to use,
>   copy, cache, publish, display, distribute, modify, create derivative
>   works .....

Traducido rapidamente al español.. todo lo que ponemos aca, pertenece a SO.

te recomendaria leer tambien [¿Cómo funciona la eliminación de publicaciones? ¿Por qué podría eliminarse una publicación y qué implica? ¿Cuál es el criterio para eliminar?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1033/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-eliminaci%C3%B3n-de-publicaciones-por-qu%C3%A9-podr%C3%ADa-eliminarse-una-p)

Es una pena verte partir. Mas allá de algunos desacuerdos en la forma de manejar ciertas preguntas/respuestas, se viene un cambio importante con entrada de moderadores elegidos por nosotros, y esperamos que se genere un cambio en la forma de manejar todas las cosas. Tienes respuestas importantes, y si hay problemas personales siempre se pueden hablar.

Comment: Gracias. Leeré la cláusula. Si abandonas el sitio por haber recibido ofensas personales creo que sería posible demandar formalmente que tu contenido sea retirado. Veré si dice algo a ese respecto.

Comment: Creo que si recibiste ofensas personales, deberias elevar el tema. Como te decia, puedes participar activamente de la eleccion, y despues plantear este tema.. Alejarte un rato de las controversias y ver que se puede hacer. Hasta ahora no habiamos tenido elecciones, y si te tomas un tiempo para leer las postulaciones y el cuestionario, te daras cuenta que todo el mundo se lo esta tomando muy seriamente.Te invito a que te tomes un respiro, participes en la eleccion, y despues volverte a plantear este tema.

Comment: @A.Cedano No es posible que todo tu contenido quede eliminado, ni siquiera si ganas un juicio... Ellos tienen backup de todo. incluso si borran los backup solo los borran del sistema de archivos, pero la información puede ser recuperada con algún programa como el recuva.

Comment: @ArtEze no creo que la pregunta esté apuntando a ver si existe un borrado físico total

Comment: @gbianchi: Ya lo mencionó el OP en su pregunta, pero va por aquí para que te llegue una notificación: El otorgar una licencia de uso no hace que SO se vuelva el propietario del contenido.

Comment: @ruben no entendreria como no. No es de ellos pq no pueden decir q lo escribieron. Pero si es de ellos pq nombrando al autor pueden hacer lo que quieran. O eso por lo menos entiendo  se desprende del acuerdo de uso

Comment: @gbianchi: El decir que "es de ellos..." es un forma de hablar imprecisa que para alguien que no esté familiarizado con lo que aquí sucede lo conduce a la confusión y el error. El tema es complejo como para explicarlo en un comentario. De forma muy suscinta, te comparto que al tema en México se le llama Propiedad Intelectual y es un tema que no está del todo claro y por ende cuando se complican las cosas un juicio puede llegar a ser costosísimo para las partes involucradas. Te lo menciono con base en los talleres que sobre la materia he tomado.

Comment: @gbianchi En los paises firmantes de la convención de Berne el autor de una obra publicada es otorgado automáticamente la propiedad intelectual de esa obra. Esta propiedad puede ser cedida o vendida. Pero no es eso lo que sucede en este caso. Al publicar en SO se concede por parte del autor una licencia CC-BY-SA 3.0 a SO del contenido publicado. Licencia perpetua y no revocable. Por lo que SO puede seguir publicando ese contenido bajo licencia CC-BY-SA 3.0 incluso aunque el autor no quiera. SO sin embargo no puede publicar ese contenido bajo una licencia distinta...

Comment: ...puesto que no tiene la propiedad intelectual del Trabajo. El autor original sí puede publicar ese contenido bajo cualquier licencia, lo cual incluye pero no se limita a publicar ese contenido sin citar a Stack Overflow. Y lo puede hacer porque es el titular de la propiedad intelectual del Trabajo.

Answer (score 2):

No puedes borrar el contenido porque no es tuyo. Según el punto 3 de los [términos del servicio](https://stackexchange.com/legal) todas tus contribuciones fueron cedidas por tí a SE de forma perpetua e irrevocable.

No me queda claro si puedes usar el contenido que tu creaste en otro sitio, pero creo que no, así que solo debes recordar citar la licencia y la fuente.

Comment: Gracias. En ese caso puedo borrar _mi_ contenido manualmente ¿no?

Comment: Aplica la pregunta que cita Rubén. Además se pueden recuperar si se proponen y votan en ese sentido.

Comment: @A.Cedano no todo tu contenido, por ejemplo no una respuesta aceptada, o las otras excepciones de la pregunta duplicada. De todas formas, eliminar masivamente suele ser detectado como una acción no deseada y puede llegar a que se recupere y termines suspendido

Comment: @A.Cedano al borrar tu contenido, un moderador lo recuperará. Que seas el autor del contenido no significa que sea tuyo.

Comment: @Mariano y no se pueden eliminar más de 5 publicaciones al día.

Comment: Esto es completamente falso. No te has leido el punto 3. No hay cesión  a SO. El contenido (que sea original) publicado por A. Cedano es propiedad intelectual de A. Cedano y solo de A. Cedano. No es propiedad intelectual de Stack Overflow. Lo que tiene Stack Overflow es una licencia CC-BY-SA 3.0 para publicar ese contenido que fue concedida por A. Cedano a Stack Overflow. Y este es el motivo por el que SO puede seguir publicando ese contenido aún en contra del deseo de A. Cedano.

Comment: @A.Cedano Y por supuesto que sí puedes usar tu contenido como quieras. De hecho puedes usarlo bajo una licencia distinta a CC-BY-SA 3.0. Al ser el propietario de los derechos del autor del contenido por ti publicado (el que sea original) puedes publicarlo como quieras y además puedes extender licencias de cualquier tipo de ese contenido a quien quieras.

Comment: Gracias @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos Me parecía extraño que SO se apropiase de _mi_ contenido y que luego no pueda usarlo donde quiera. En efecto, el punto 3 traducido **no dice que yo ceda la propiedad de mi contenido**: _Usted acepta que todo el Contenido del Suscriptor que Usted aporta a la Red está perpetuamente e irrevocablemente **licenciado** a Stack Exchange bajo la licencia Creative Commons Reconocimiento ... Usted otorga a Stack Exchange el derecho y la licencia perpetua e irrevocable de **usar, copiar, archivar, publicar, mostrar, distribuir, modificar, crear trabajos derivados**._

Comment: @LuiggiMendozaJ Si soy el autor del contenido, el contenido es mío y sólo mío. He colocado en comentario la traducción del punto 3. Yo otorgo **una _licencia_ a SO, no la propiedad de mi contenido.** Esta respuesta es por tanto errónea.

Comment: @A.Cedano bueno, por algo existe el ban por eliminación de contenido útil, inclusive aunque borres el contenido supuestamente tuyo (porque, nuevamente, **no es tuyo**).

Comment: @LuiggiMendozaJ Según la respuesta de José Antonio, citada en la edición de la pregunta, **puedo retirar la licencia que he otorgado a SO de usar mi contenido**, si recibo agravio por parte de alguien que represente a SO, por ejemplo un empleado de SO y (quizá)  un moderador. El contenido **es del autor**, y SO apela a la licencia otorgada para usarlo, pero esa licencia puede ser revocada por causas justificadas.

Comment: @A.Cedano Es un poco más complicado que eso. Solo puedes retirar la licencia si recibes ofensa **en relación al Trabajo**. Una ofensa general que no esté relacionada con el Trabajo no te permite retirar la licencia. Y solo te permitiría retirar la licencia de ese Trabajo en particular, no de todos. Yo abandonaría tu intento de borrar el contenido, no te va a llevar a ninguna parte. En lo que sí se equivoca Mendoza (y van ya dos veces) es al afirmar que el contenido no es tuyo. Sí lo es. Pero no puedes, en general, retirar la licencia.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos Por más que Mendoza diga que el contenido no es mío, sí lo es y puedo usarlo como me parezca y donde me parezca. De hecho, me pregunto si sería o no una buena idea (o si es permitido) responder en SO con código firmado, es decir, que indique el autor y el tipo de licencia.

Comment: @A.Cedano Sí, sí. Es tuyo y puedes publicarlo donde quieras y sin tener que citar a SO. Pero no puedes retirar a SO la licencia. Y los agravios que has recibido no tienen suficiente entidad legal como para permitirte retirar la licencia.