# Alternativas al borrado de contenido

Tags: discusión, eliminación-de-preguntas, eliminación-de-respuestas

Si un usuario quiere borrar todo el contenido que él ha publicado en el sitio no va a poder puesto que SO tiene una licencia CC-BY-SA 3.0 para publicar ese contenido.

¿Qué otras posibilidades hay?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## No puedes desasociar contenido

La licencia CC-BY-SA 3.0 te permite desasociar contenido. Pero el contenido que publicas en StackOverflow se hace bajo licencia doble. CC-BY-SA-3.0 y [Los términos de Uso (en inglés)](https://stackexchange.com/legal).

> #### 3. Subscriber Content
>
> You agree that all Subscriber Content that You contribute to the
> Network is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange
> under the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license. You grant
> Stack Exchange the perpetual and irrevocable right and license to use,
> copy, cache, publish, display, distribute, modify, create derivative
> works and store such Subscriber Content and

Esa licencia extra que recibe Stack Overflow le permite mantener tu publicación y mantenerlo asociado a tu persona incluso en contra de tu voluntad.


## Desasociar contenido.

Puedes desasociar tu contenido de tu persona completamente.

Te ampara la sección 4a de la licencia [Creative Commons](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode)

> **4** Restrictions. The license granted in Section 3 above is expressly made subject to and limited by the following restrictions:
>
> **a.** You may Distribute or Publicly Perform the Work only under the terms of this License. You must include a copy of, or the Uniform
> Resource Identifier (URI) for, this License with every copy of the
> Work You Distribute or Publicly Perform. You may not offer or impose
> any terms on the Work that restrict the terms of this License or the
> ability of the recipient of the Work to exercise the rights granted to
> that recipient under the terms of the License. You may not sublicense
> the Work. You must keep intact all notices that refer to this License
> and to the disclaimer of warranties with every copy of the Work You
> Distribute or Publicly Perform. When You Distribute or Publicly
> Perform the Work, You may not impose any effective technological
> measures on the Work that restrict the ability of a recipient of the
> Work from You to exercise the rights granted to that recipient under
> the terms of the License. This Section 4(a) applies to the Work as
> incorporated in a Collection, but this does not require the Collection
> apart from the Work itself to be made subject to the terms of this
> License. If You create a Collection, upon notice from any Licensor You
> must, to the extent practicable, remove from the Collection any credit
> as required by Section 4(c), as requested. If You create an
> Adaptation, upon notice from any Licensor You must, to the extent
> practicable, remove from the Adaptation any credit as required by
> Section 4(c), as requested.

Es decir, cuando tu trabajo sea publicado en una colección puedes como licenciante del trabajo (el autor) notificar al licenciatario (Stack Overflow) que quieres que se retire todo crédito a tu persona requerido por la sección 4c.

La cuestión de la notificación puede verse atrasada por la cuestión de la identidad. Por este motivo es mejor que no borres tu cuenta. En lugar de ello:

- Cambia el nombre de tu cuenta a "Usuario que se va" o algo por el estilo.
- Borra tus datos personales de tu perfil.
- Añade a tu perfil un texto indicando que deseas desasociar tu contenido de tu persona.
- Usa la [página de contacto](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) para pedir que se desasocie todo el contenido que has publicado de tu persona. Menciona la sección 4a de la licencia CC-BY-SA 3.0. También puedes pedir que se desasocie una pregunta o respuesta en particular en vez de todo tu contenido.
- Nunca borres tu cuenta. El hacerlo no va a contribuir a tu objetivo de borrar el contenido y sí te va a dificultar las escasas posibilidades que tienes de borrar tu contenido.

El procedimiento aquí descrito, en particular el utilizar la página de contacto, coincide con lo que en SO esperan que hagas como indicó [Tim Post's en su respuesta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291837/2415822) a [Why is this heavily downvoted question not yet removed from Meta Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291770/2415822) (traducido) :

> Puedes contactarnos y pedir que lo desasociemos de tu cuenta,
> estaremos encantados de hacerlo. La pregunta será asociada a un
> usuario anónimo "persona misteriosa" y ya no estará enlazado a ti.

## No hay terminación de licencia aunque SO viole los términos de CC-BY-SA 3.0

Aunque se diese el caso de que SO violase los términos de CC-BY-SA 3.0 SO seguiría disponiendo de la licencia extra otorgada por los términos de uso. La licencia CC-BY-SA 3.0 dejaría de ser válida pero la otorgada por los términos de uso les permite hacer lo mismo que CC-BY-SA 3.0 y algunas cosas más.

## Terminación de licencia.

En el improbable caso de que SO violase los términos de la licencia CC-BY-SA 3.0 dejaría de tener el derecho de publicar tu contenido.
Especialmente relevante es la sección 4d:

> **d.** Except as otherwise agreed in writing by the Licensor or as may be
> otherwise permitted by applicable law, if You Reproduce, Distribute or
> Publicly Perform the Work either by itself or as part of any
> Adaptations or Collections, You must not distort, mutilate, modify or
> take other derogatory action in relation to the Work which would be
> prejudicial to the Original Author's honor or reputation. Licensor
> agrees that in those jurisdictions (e.g. Japan), in which any exercise
> of the right granted in Section 3(b) of this License (the right to
> make Adaptations) would be deemed to be a distortion, mutilation,
> modification or other derogatory action prejudicial to the Original
> Author's honor and reputation, the Licensor will waive or not assert,
> as appropriate, this Section, to the fullest extent permitted by the
> applicable national law, to enable You to reasonably exercise Your
> right under Section 3(b) of this License (right to make Adaptations)
> but not otherwise.

Si SO realizase una acción que "distorsionase, mutilase, modificase o fuese derogatoria en relación al Trabajo que fuese perjudicial para el honor o reputación del Autor Original" entonces la licencia quedaría nula.
Por supuesto el que un usuario cualquiera te insulte no activa esa sección. Los usuarios cualquiera no representan a SO. Sí la activaría el que un empleado de SO que representa a SO te insulte en relación al Trabajo. Y es discutible que la activase el que te insulte un moderador con diamante en relación al Trabajo, el argumento a favor sería por ejemplo la siguiente afirmación de Atwood :

> As a moderator, your actions now represent the community, so you will
> be held to a higher standard of behavior. You are an ambassador of
> trust, with the same sorts of rights that the official development
> team and community coordinators have.

### No irte

Otra alternativa sería solucionar el problema que tengas y seguir en el sitio. Pero eso ya es decisión de cada cual.

### Borrar comentarios.

No vas a poder borrar tus preguntas y respuestas. Pero sí puedes borrar tus comentarios. Los comentarios son efímeros en SO (efímeros de una duración muy larga, como el soon™ de Blizzard) y nadie se va a molestar en recuperarlos.

### El [efecto Streisand](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efecto_Streisand)

Independientemente de lo que digan las leyes o lo que haga SO ten en cuenta que publicaste tu contenido en Internet.
Cuanto más famoso sea tu contenido tanto más difícil es eliminarlo de la red. Los tribunales de justicia del país más poderoso del planeta no pueden hacerlo. Tu menos.

### Error: Borrar tu cuenta

Esto no es una alternativa, es un **error**.
Borrar tu cuenta no provoca que se borre tu contenido y sí te dificulta las escasas posibilidades que tienes de hacerlo.
Si aún así quieres hacerlo tienes instrucciones en [¿Cómo borro mi cuenta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account)

Comment: Considero que se debería hacer referencia a [¿Cómo borro mi cuenta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account) en particular que ahí se menciona  (énfasis mío) : ¡El borrado de usuarios es irreversible! Tras enviar esta petición, tus votos serán revocados y **todo tu contenido será anonimizado**. Sin embargo, la recomendación que haces de cambiar el nombre y no borrar la cuenta me parece muy valiosa por las razones que mencionas.