# ¿Cómo puedo borrar mi cuenta? ¿Qué pasa con el contenido que he publicado?

Tags: soporte, faq, eliminación-de-usuarios, cuentas-de-usuario

¿Cómo puedo eliminar mi cuenta de Stack Exchange?

¿Qué pasa con el contenido que he publicado cuando mi cuenta se borra?

> Para más información, véase [¿Cómo borro mi cuenta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account) en el [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help).

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para borrar tu cuenta, puedes seguir las instrucciones de [¿Cómo borro mi cuenta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account) disponibles en el Centro de Ayuda.

1. **Si tu cuenta ha votado o publicado una sola vez**, deberías ver la opción de eliminar tú mismo en tu página de perfil:

   1. Ve a tu perfil de usuario
   2. Pulsa en la pestaña *Edición de perfil y configuración*
   3. Pulsa en la opción de eliminar la cuenta
2. **Si has votado o publicado más de una vez**, entonces esta opción no estará disponible y tendrás que [mandar un formulario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/contact) a Stack Exchange pidiendo que borren tu cuenta mediante la opción *Necesito eliminar mi perfil de usuario*.

**Notas**:

Deberás realizar la petición de eliminación en cada uno de los sitios en los que participas.

El contenido que has publicado en Stack Exchange [te pertenece pero está autorizado a Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18221/who-owns-the-content-i-post), por lo que las solicitudes de borrarlo junto a tu cuenta son generalmente rechazadas.

Comment: @Jose ese _las solicitudes de borrarlo son generalmente rechazadas_ parece indicar que hay casos en que sí son aceptadas. ¿Ha sido así alguna vez?

Comment: @fedorqui Si publicas algo copiado y después descubres que habías interpretado incorrectamente la licencia de lo que copiaste y no tenías permiso para publicarlo en SO entonces puedes pedir a SO que lo borren y SO estaría en la obligación de hacerlo. Hay otras situaciones en que SO aceptaría borrar. Pero no son habituales, por lo que generalmente esas peticiones son rechazadas.