# Criterio de voto en Meta

Tags: discusión, votos, meta

¿Cómo votais vosotros en *Meta*?

A raíz de un intercambio de comentarios en [esta pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2237/83) y tras leer los enlaces que proporcionó @fedorqui: uno en [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187018/voting-on-meta-is-not-just-for-disagreement-update-the-help-center-to-reflect) y otro de la propia ayuda de [StackOverflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) me he dado cuenta de que mi criterio de voto en algunas publicaciones de *Meta* quizá no fuera el correcto.

Yo siempre había pensado que en se votaba para mostrar acuerdo o desacuerdo con la cuestión planteada pero por lo visto esto solo es así cuando se usa la etiqueta [característica-nueva](/questions/tagged/caracter%c3%adstica-nueva). Por lo que se habló en la pregunta a la que hago referencia, otros comentarios que he leído y los votos en algunas preguntas y respuestas creo que hay más gente que pensaba como yo.

Lo que me gustaría saber es si es general el criterio de votar acuerdo/desacuerdo en *Meta* o es algo aislado.

Comment: Me parece interesante consultar sobre cómo votamos en Meta. En cuanto a la redacción, me parece que la pregunta no es tan clara como podría ser. Primero empieza con una intención a la cual corresponde [meta-tag:soporte] y luego en una "adenda" la intención se cambia radicalmente a la cual correspondería [meta-tag:discusión].  Siendo que la pregunta tienes pocos votos (dos) me parece que sería mejor hacer una revisión "orgánica", es decir decir en un principio que se trata una consulta para que quede claro que se esperan opiniones y que los votos sería para manifestar el estar de acuerdo o no.

Comment: Y dejar lo del intercambio de comentarios mas abajo para dar contexto.

Comment: @Rubén Edítala como quieras. La he planteado según a surgido el debate y después fedorqui ha puesto el enlace a la ayuda y he estado a punto de borrarla

Comment: @Rubén He reescrito la pregunta, creo que así está más claro.

Answer (score 3):

Viendo que últimamente ha habido cierta polémica con este tema, y aunque esta pregunta es bastante antigua, voy a agregar una respuesta con mi criterio personal.

El tema de los votos en los sitios meta de la red StackExchange es tan [antiguo como la propia red](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75049/346768). En el enlace anterior se propuso que se modificara el tooltip que aparece al ponerse sobre los botones de votación en los sitios de meta, y se descartó (aunque parece que en contra del criterio de la mayoría, por decisión de Jeff Atwood, cuya respuesta cuenta ahora mismo con 53 votos negativos.

Como otra fuente tenemos [esta publicación en meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/47634/), que en [esta respuesta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47635/) especifica lo siguiente:

> *Unlike* normal Stack Exchange sites, Meta Stack Exchange invites the community to discuss, debate and propose changes to the way the community itself behaves, as well as how the software itself works. On many posts, especially feature requests, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself.

Esto es:

> *A diferencia* de los sitios normales de Stack Exchange, Meta Stack Exchange invita a la comunidad a discutir, debatir y proponer cambios a la forma en la que la propia comunidad se comporta, así como a cómo el software mismo funciona. En muchas publicaciones, especialmente solicitudes de funcionalidades, votar indica acuerdo o desacuerdo con el cambio propuesto en lugar de simplemente la calidad o utilidad de la publicación en si misma.

Una vez mostrados los antecedentes, mi opinión personal. Yo considero que todas las publicaciones en meta son pertinentes (excepto lógicamente las que estén fuera de la temática y que deben en tal caso ser cerradas, no votadas negativamente), por la que para mi carece de sentido votarlas para indicar, como en el sitio principal, que la pregunta *es útil y clara*. Todas las preguntas en meta son útiles, ya que expresan una inquietud de algún miembro y son la forma mas directa de contactar con la comunidad.

Para mi, votarlas expresa única y exclusivamente si el que vota está o no de acuerdo con lo que se expresa en dicha publicación (bien sea una solicitud, bien sea una opinión).

Esta es lógicamente mi opinión personal (*que podéis votar negativamente con total tranquilidad :)*) y que abarca a la práctica totalidad de publicaciones en este sitio. Tal vez exista alguna excepción que se me escapa, pero no se me ocurre ninguna en este momento.

Comment: Qué bueno que plantees el debate de nuevo. El texto que pones está más sucinto en el artículo del Centro de Ayuda
 [¿Qué es "meta" y cómo funciona?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) y dice _Sobre preguntas etiquetadas [meta-tag:feature-request], votar indica acuerdo o desacuerdo_.