# ¿Qué hacer con "Parece que tu publicación es mayormente código; por favor, añade más detalles"?

Tags: soporte, preguntas, advertencias-en-preguntas

En ocasiones recibo este mensaje al formatear una pregunta:

> Parece que tu publicación es mayormente código; por favor, añade más detalles.

Es muy molesto, porque a veces se explica el problema en detalle. Sin embargo, el código proporcionado es más grande que la explicación y aparece este mensaje. Es un mensaje que no deja hacer la pregunta o la modificación del código del OP.

Las soluciones que se me ocurren no son muy buenas:

1. Añadir texto banal para que desaparezca el mensaje, ya que ya se ha detallado el problema.
2. Dejar el código sin formatear.

Creo que este mensaje no es una buena solución al hecho de que algunas personas no expliquen su problema correctamente. Hay preguntas que contienen mayormente código pero están bien planteadas y explicadas en detalle.

Comment: Qué manía se tiene últimamente a cascar negativos a las preguntas de Meta

Comment: @fedorqui tal vez no entendemos igual los votos negativos en meta. Yo siempre he considerado que votar en contra indica desacuerdo con la propuesta, no que la pregunta no sea buena/pertinente.

Comment: @fedorqui [relacionado](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2552/15301)

Answer (score 5):

Tal vez deberias revisar que es un [MCVE (Ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Si tenes que escribir una pared de código y tu explicacion es corta, seguramente hay algo que este mal.

El codigo debe ser el minimo para reproducir y mostrar el problema, y la explicación debe ser maxima de que cosas intentaste e investigaste.

Si las cosas estan al reves, seguramente no esten del todo correcta.

Comment: Hola, ya lo hice y sigo pensando que en algunos casos, es imposible reducir más el código. De hecho, en la propia guía dice "Mínimo no implica breve". Seguramente en la mayoría de casos es como dices, pero no siempre.

Comment: Claro.. pero si es mucho codigo, y la explicacion es muy corta, el problema sigue estando en la explicacion. o lo que intentaste...

Comment: "Lo que intenté" comporta aún más código, y muchas veces se añaden los comentarios en el propio código por legibilidad. Al final, lo que hago, es acabar poniendo una explicación más larga que no añade ningún tipo de información relevante. Pero es así.

Comment: Estos son los casos donde hay que ver publicacion por publicacion. Puede que en alguna tengas razon.. pero eso no implica que sea asi para todas.

Answer (score 4):

Este mensaje se implementó hace poco a raíz de la pregunta [¿Están de acuerdo con poner una validación a preguntas que son código unicamente?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3743/83). Al revisar números a raíz de [¿Con qué frecuencia los usuarios nuevos utilizan las imágenes en sustitución de explicaciones?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4013/83) se observó que con cierta frecuencia, los usuarios nuevos ponían más énfasis en poner código que en explicar qué querían. Para evitar que esto sea así, en su respuesta avisando de que este aviso está activo, el CM Nicolas [comentó](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4051/83):

> Hemos activado dos verificaciones a este respecto:
>
> - La verificación #1 impone una cierta relación entre líneas de código y caracteres de texto en una pregunta. Con demasiado código / demasiado poco texto la pregunta será rechazada con un mensaje solicitando una explicación más extendida del código.
> - La verificación #2 establece un umbral por debajo del cual las aportaciones de los usuarios serán comprobadas usando a un conjunto de heurísticas para intentar identificar código que no está adecuadamente formateado como tal.
>
> Ambas comprobaciones son configurables. Por el momento la #1 está establecida como "6 caracteres de texto por 1 línea de código", y la #2 está establecida a "200 puntos de reputación". Durante las próximas semanas tenemos que vigilar los números y ajustar las verificaciones, o desactivarlas si algo va mal.

En tu caso #2 aplica porque no llegas a los 200 puntos y  al parecer la densidad de código es alta.

Yo creo que el aviso es bueno que esté. Tu caso puede ser un caso extremo, pero en general es bueno siempre tener en cuenta [lo que comenta gbianchi en su buena respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4173/83): no hay necesidad de poner muros de código. Limítate a lo estricto necesario y pon énfasis en explicar qué quieres hacer con palabras y no con código.

Si nos da alguna referencia de pregunta donde esté pasando esto y tú creas que es injusto, menciónala y la repasamos juntos.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, muy detallada y bien explicada. En mi caso, antes de publicar la única pregunta que he hecho en SO https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/267431/error-cannot-read-property-data-en-angular-material-table tuve que añadir esta línea para poder publicar "Soy nueva con Angular, y más aún con Angular Material, por lo que la pregunta puede ser un poco confusa.", aunque con la edición posterior no habría sido necesario. También es molesto cuando intento formatear preguntas de otra gente, y ahí no entro a valorar si están bien o mal planteadas.

Comment: Revisando tu pregunta, @PrettyAvocado, veo que incluyes mucho código que probablemente no es necesario. Sí es bueno que incluyas todos los archivos, pero detallar todos los métodos que tiene cada archivo parece excesivo y no ayuda sino dificulta la comprensión de la pregunta. Entiendo que es normal añadir de más si eres nueva en la tecnología y no sabes dónde puede haber el problema, pero muchas veces es de más ayuda un comentario diciendo *// salto líneas* o *// esta parte solo valida datos, no las pongo*, y así la gente puede ver lo importante de un vistazo.

Comment: El problema en este caso es que yo no sé qué parte es importante y qué no lo es, y pongo lo que he hecho hasta ese momento. Puede que sobre código, pero no creo que falte explicar nada, y si no sé qué parte del código sobra supongo que es mejor pecar de precavida. Gracias por la respuesta, lo tendré en cuenta, pero a veces es un poco difícil.

Comment: @PrettyAvocado Si no sabes que parte es importante y que parte no, mas a nuestro favor para recomendarte un MCVE. seguramente mucho de eso no tenga importancia a tu problema en particular. Y probar un programita que reproduzca solo tu problema, muchas veces te va a ayudar a resolverlos.

Comment: @PrettyAvocado como señala gbianchi lo mejor es crear un MCVE, aunque suele ser complicado la primera vez pero un punto de inicio es borrar codigo y ver como afecta al problema, si el problema persiste aun con la eliminación entonces podemos deducir que esa parte no es importante y por lo tanto no debe ser parte de un MCVE.